# How to include list in str with %? python question

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, printing

I was recently started to learn one more programming language, Python. but I stuck with one problem in chapter String formating.

My question as we include integers, floating numbers, variables etc. in string by symbols like %c or %d, is there is a way to include list directly without splitting in numbers of variables?

```py
foo = [1, 3, "this is str."]#list
print("The massage is '%SOMETHING ' ", foo)
```

Comment: `%s` works for anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, you can insert lists into strings with the format string method like the following:
1) `print("The message is {}".format(list))`
or 
2) `print("The message is {ls}".format(ls=list))`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals) on python 3.6+.

Just use

```py
v_list = [3.6, 'as', 4]
print(f'Showing {v_list}')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can conver the list to a string using str():

```
foo = [1, 2,' this is str']
print("This is your list: '", str(foo), "' and its great!")
```

The out put will be:

```
This is your list: '[1, 2,' this is str']' and its great!
```